# KDB windowed join with aggregation function on columns from both tables

Tags: kdb

This is an extension question to [How to do a between join clause in KDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57845802/how-to-do-a-between-join-clause-in-kdb)

Suppose I have a table A with the columns bucket_start_date, bucket_end_date,

```
A
bucket_start_date | bucket_end_date
2015.05.02        | 2015.05.08
2015.05.08        | 2015.05.12
```

Also suppose i have a table B with the columns date, coins.

```
A
date        | coins
2015.05.02  | 5
2015.05.06  | 11     
2015.05.09  | 32
```

How do I do a join in kdb that logically looks like

select A.bucket_start_date, A.bucket_end_date, sum((B.date - A.bucket_start_date) * B.coins)  from A join B where B.date BETWEEN A.bucket_start_date and A.bucket_end_date group by A.bucket_start_date, A.bucket_end_date

What i want is a column of weighted sum of coins weighted by the distance to start date instead of just a simple sum of columns. Aka coins that are closer to bucket_start_date have a lower weight in the sum than the coins farther away from bucket_start_date.

wj1's documentation only talks about aggregation columns on the 2nd table, how do i write a aggregation function that also takes into consideration of the fields in the 1st table of the join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the window join from your previous question by adding an additional aggregation function on the date column, like so:

```
q)show w:wj1[A`bucket_start_date`bucket_end_date;`date;A;(B;(sum;`coins);(::;`date))]
bucket_start_date bucket_end_date coins date
-------------------------------------------------------------
2015.05.02        2015.05.08      16    2015.05.02 2015.05.06
2015.05.08        2015.05.12      32    ,2015.05.09
q)show w:ungroup w
bucket_start_date bucket_end_date coins date
--------------------------------------------------
2015.05.02        2015.05.08      16    2015.05.02
2015.05.02        2015.05.08      16    2015.05.06
2015.05.08        2015.05.12      32    2015.05.09
```

At the end of the window join, you can add the identity function `(::)` which will simply output the input, which in this case is the dates of the date column of the B table which fall inside the respective window. Also use the [ungroup](https://code.kx.com//v2/ref/ungroup/) keyword to "explode" the table so that this new date column is not a list of dates.

Using this table `w`, a select statement (very much like the one you provided) can get the weighted sum of coins:

```
q)select sum coins*date-bucket_start_date by bucket_start_date,bucket_end_date from w
bucket_start_date bucket_end_date| coins
---------------------------------| -----
2015.05.02        2015.05.08     | 64
2015.05.08        2015.05.12     | 32
```

You can reorder the operations in the select statement to avoid the need for brackets!

EDIT:

To answer your follow up, I modified the `wj1` to get a table similar to what your question needs:

```
q)t:wj1[A`bucket_start_date`bucket_end_date;`date;A;(B;(::;`coins);(::;`date))]
q)t
bucket_start_date bucket_end_date coins    date
----------------------------------------------------------------
2015.05.02        2015.05.08      5 11     2015.05.02 2015.05.06
2015.05.08        2015.05.12      ,32      ,2015.05.09
2015.05.12        2015.05.18      `long$() `date$()
```

One way of selecting empty rows is to count each row and take all the rows that have a count of 0:

```
q)select from t where not count each coins
bucket_start_date bucket_end_date coins date
--------------------------------------------
2015.05.12        2015.05.18
```

We can see what the where clause is doing by breaking it down step by step:

```
q)t`coins
5 11
,32
`long$()
q)count each t`coins
2 1 0
q)not count each t`coins
001b
```

The final line uses a quick way of converting longs to booleans by using the [not](https://code.kx.com/v2/ref/not/) keyword. In this case, `not` will return `1b` for each long which is 0, and `0b` for each non-zero long.

Comment: If there are no entries from B that is within a given range, I get something like
`long$() in the coins column and `date$() in the dates column. How do i match on these entries? AKA how do i query all rows from the above table where the coins list is an empty list